# Creating dictionary from a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
age,name
3,abc
5,xyz
6,pqr
4,stu
8,lkm
```

How can I put this in a dictionary in the following format:

```
{3:'abc', 5:'xyz', 6:'pqr', 4:'stu', 8:'lkm'}
```

UPDATE:

mycode-

```
age_file = open('age.csv','r')
csv_age = csv.DictReader(age_file)

for row in csv_age:
    print(row)
```

> > OUTPUT:

```
{'age' : 3, 'name' : 'abc', 'age' : 5, 'name' : xyz, ... }
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed not to have any entries with duplicate ages?

Comment: follow up to that question: are you sure you dont want the key/values switched so that the name maps to their age?

Comment: I could not post the entire file and i apologize for not pointing that out but yes, there will be duplicate value. But that does not mean i will only append one of those. 
If my file has 3,3,3 as age then i will have 3,3,3 in my dictionary as a key also and the value will be the corresponding name.

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes i tried those methods but i keep getting an error saying that list object can only be int, or slices and not str.

Comment: @RNar I don't mind if the key/values are switched. 
My main goal is to put this information in a dictionary such that i have a key and a value.
Probably key being the age and value being the name

Comment: @Luke how did you try those methods? that error sounds really strange to me...

Comment: @Luke without seeing what you have tried before, we cannot know. So far, your question is a duplicate of dozen others. Please, provide code and then we can point you out to the problem.

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes i updated it with my code.

Comment: @Luke So you're reading the file using `cvs.DictReader`, which is legit. Then you iterate over the rows. For each row you get a dictionary `{'age': <value under age column>, 'name': <value under name column>}`. You can build a new dictionary, entry by entry, by taking those values. I still don't see where you could get the error you mention. It would be useful to see the piece of code that gives you *that*

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes alright i got it!!

i used .strip().split() method
and did something like my_dict = { age : number }

Thansk for all the help!

Comment: Good. You could have used the results from `csv.DictReader`, though (or `csv.reader`, for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

Except problem came from age and name. If name/age are uniq, you can use :

```
import csv
my_result={}
with open('age.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     for age,name in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
         my_result[age]=name
```

but I hope a defaultdict better for your use. And make it more robust from having more than one name for one age:

```
import csv
from collection import defaultdict 
my_result=defaultdict(list)
with open('age.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
         my_result[age].append(name)
```

In this case, the result will be:
{1:["bob","john"],3:["bill"],6:["Georges","Monica"]}

Comment: for part two of your code, shell gives me an error saying that dict object has no attribute append.

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy so I use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dd = {}
for ii, age in enumerate(df.age):
    dd[age] = df.name.iloc[ii]
```

However, I agree with the comments above that you'll clobber previous entries that have a given age as a key the next time that same age shows up as a key.